# Given process ID, find environment variables

Tags: c++, windows, variables, process, environment

I need to be able to read the environment variables of another running process in windows. The code that I am writing requires me to read them prior to a process running it's code.

Say there are two applications. I first run application #1. Once I run the application #2, application #1 will first read the environment variables of the second application (just reading them) before letting the second application run it's code.

Notes:

1. Application #1 does not call `CreateProcess` for application #2.
2. Application #2 can be any application that the user has specified in application #1
3. Application #2 can be launched by shortcuts on the desktop, through other applications and launchers.
4. Application #1 can use `PsSetLoadImageNotifyRoutine` to get `FullImageName`, `ProcessID`, `ImageInfo`.

Comment: I'm not sure it matters that much. The started process could set environment variables *after* having been started.

Comment: @HarryJohnston: I edited the question to provide more information. Hope that helps. As for the launcher idea, I think problems might occur if application #2 has its own launcher. The code that I am writing has to occur between application #2 and application #2's launcher. I do think hooking CreateProcess will work, but hooking seems very dangerous.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch: The environment variables will affect the settings of application #2. I think application#2 will crash if I apply the changes after having started.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use `PsSetCreateProcessNotifyRoutineEx` in your driver component the callback routine receives a pointer to the [EPROCESS structure](http://www.nirsoft.net/kernel_struct/vista/EPROCESS.html).  You can find a pointer to the environment block here:

```
Process->Peb->ProcessParameters->Environment
```

(Of course these are undocumented structures, but I don't think there's any supported way to do what you're asking for.)

Comment: I try to access the environment block like so, but it won't compile.<br/>

'PVOID pEnvironment = (PVOID)Process->Peb->ProcessParameters->Environment;'<br/>

Answer (score 0):

To set the environment used by an application you are launching,  launch application #2 using [CreateProcess](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-createprocessa) and pass in the the environment variables you want application #2 to have using the `lpEnvironment` parameter.

You can get application #1's current environment using [GetEnvironmentStrings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processenv/nf-processenv-getenvironmentstrings).

Comment: There's a problem where application #2 can be from a list of possible applications the user defines. I can't just call CreateProcess with application #1 because application #1 will never know what exactly application #2 is. However application #1 can be notified when a process is about to be created. It then needs to determine if that application is in the user defined list before applying changes to the environment variables. If it's not in the list, application #1 will just leave it alone.

Comment: @Informat: what mechanism are you using to intercept the process creation?

Comment: Is a process other than application #1 launching these user defined applications?  Something must be using CreateProcess (or a wrapper for it) to launch them.

Comment: @HarryJohnston: the OS will inform application #1 when a process is created or terminated - lots of black magic

Comment: @shf301: Application #2 can be launched from the desktop or be launched from some other unknown application.

Comment: @HarryJohnston: Also, application #1 will have a NT kernel-mode driver component as well as a user-mode component. the kernel-mode driver component will be using the APIs PsSetCreateProcessNotifyRoutine() (unless there's an easier way of doing it)